# Apache POI Trouble With Font

Tags: java, excel, apache, fonts, apache-poi

I am getting a strange error using Apache POI version 3.15 (currently the most recent stable non-beta build) and my internet searches do not show anyone else with this error. I am trying to simply bold a cell, for example:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
font.setBold(true);
```

Already I run into an issue where it claims the font the workbook is creating isn't a HSSFFont, but some normal font:

> incompatible types: Font cannot be converted to HSSFFont

I've tried creating a normal font and applying it to the CellStyle, but that causes a nullPointerException when adding it to the cellStyle. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wb.createFont()` returns a `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font`, but if you inspect the runtime class of the `Font` it returns, it is actually a `HSSFFont`. You can try casting to a `HSSFFont` or just accessing it as a `Font`:

```
final Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

final HSSFFont hssfFont = (HSSFFont)wb.createFont();
hssfFont.setBold(true);

final Font font = wb.createFont();
font.setBold(true);
```